# Python- Copy folders to another location without using disutils

Tags: python

I'm iterating through a directory that contains lots of folders.  I want to copy each one of those folders from `src` to `dest`.

I have tried using `shutil's copytree`, but there is an issue involving overriding existing folders.  I see that the solution is to use disutils, but I can't download disutils because my work computer prevents installation of new packages and pip install doesn't appear to be working from work, either.

Is there an alternate solution using default packages?

Here's the code so you can understand what I'm working with:

```
import os
from os.path import join 
import shutil


def main():

    directory = "Daily_Completed_Surveys"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
       for i in dirs:
            if "POP" in i:
                src = os.path.join(root, i)
                dest = "C:\ALLPOP"
                shutil.copytree(src, dest)
```

The Daily_Completed_Surveys folder contains a structure like /[somedate]/POP[ComputerID][SomeDate]/[zipped files]

I want to get every folder labeled POP and copy them to the destination directory. (The folders themselves and the data, not just the zipped data) How do I do this?

Comment: It could be annoying, but you could delete the `dest` directory before you copy.

Comment: Thanks, Cody. Wouldn't that delete all the folders that were just copied to the dest directory?

Comment: @Parseltongue not if you delete them first and then copy over the directory trees you want.

Comment: @jbat100 I think I'm just being obtuse, but I don't understand what you mean.  I've added my code so you can see what I'm talking about

Comment: What unclear is that you use os.walk (which goes through all the files in the tree, including in the subdirectories), not just the directories in source. You can do an os.listdir() in src, then for each item check if it is a directory (an not a file), if it is check if it exists in dest (and if it does, then delete it).

Answer (score 1):

You could just check if the a directory in `src` exists in `dest`, and if it does, remove it from `dest` using `shutil.rmtree()`, then use `shutil.copytree()` to copy the directory and its content over.

Also, not being able to use `pip` somewhat sucks. If you have a proxy to the outside world you can go through that by using

```
pip install --proxy="user:password@server:port" packagename
```